# How to wrap custom future to use with asyncio in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

There is a lot of libraries that use their custom version of [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future). [kafka](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/future.py) and [s3transfer](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/s3transfer/futures.py) are just two examples: all their custom future-like classes have `object` as the superclass.

Not surprisingly, you cannot directly call `asyncio.wrap_future()` on such objects and can't use `await` with them.

What is the proper way of wrapping such futures for use with asyncio?

Comment: If you want to use `kafka` or `s3transfer` -- perhaps you don't want to work with asyncio code. At least mixing `kafka` calls inside an executor with regular async program gives expectedly slow result. The same is for `s3transfer`. What you need is `aiokafka` and `aiobotocore` usage.

Comment: We tried `aiokafka` 0.4.0 in the first place, but unfortunately it's way too buggy -- e.g., it just hangs in `position()` call or throws obscure exceptions. Just replacing it with `kafka` instantly solved all our problems.

Comment: Also, there should be no problem mixing asyncio and foreign futures as long as the blocking calls are run outside the asyncio thread, and connected to asyncio using `call_soon_threadsafe` (shown in the answer) or `run_coroutine_threadsafe`.

Comment: @kirill.shirokov sorry, I'm not Kafka expert. aiokarka is driven by my friend Taras. Sure, hi does the best and evolves the project fast. Please file a bug on github tracker if you've found a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the future class supports standard future features such as done callbacks and the `result` method, just use something like this:

```
def wrap_future(f):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    aio_future = loop.create_future()
    def on_done(*_):
        try:
            result = f.result()
        except Exception as e:
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(aio_future.set_exception, e)
        else:
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(aio_future.set_result, result)
    f.add_done_callback(on_done)
    return aio_future
```

Consider that code a template which you can customize to match the specifics of the future you are dealing with.

Intended usage is to call it from the thread that runs the asyncio event loop:

```
value = await wrap_future(some_foreign_future)
```

If you are calling it from a different thread, be sure to pass `loop` explicitly because `asyncio.get_event_loop` will fail when invoked from a thread not registered with asyncio.